# Как записать данные в базу через php?

Tags: php, mysql

сделал форму, подключил к базе данных, написал код и не могу понять почему не работает скрипт.
Подключение к базе вроде есть, данные форма получает, таблица в которую вносятся данные тоже есть
Помогите, пожалуйста

Код:

```
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','','','') or die();
//$connection = Bitrix\Main\Application::getConnection();
$msg="";

    if(isset($_POST['pcbsend'])) {
        $pcb_width=$_POST['pcbwdth'];
        $pcb_height=$_POST['pcbhght'];
        $pcb_production_time=$_POST['pcbprdtm'];
        $userId = $USER->GetID();
        $pcb_sqr = $pcb_width * $pcb_height;

        $query= "INSERT INTO `h_formtable` (`usrid`, `width`, `height`, `prodtime`, `squareofpcb`) VALUES ('$userId','$pcb_width','$pcb_height','$pcb_production_time','$pcb_sqr')";
        $data=mysqli_query($query);
        if ($data) {
            $msg="your data inserted yay!";
        }
        else {
            $msg="shit";
        }

        echo $query;

    }

<div class="userform-container container">
    <form class="userform-pcb" method="post" action="">
        <h3 class="form-name">Заказ платы</h3>
        <div class="form-inputs-group">
            <div class="inputwrap">
                <input type="number" name="pcbwdth" placeholder="мм">
            </div>
            <div class="inputwrap">
                <input type="number" name="pcbhght" placeholder="мм">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inputs-group">
            <div class="inputwrap">
                <select name="pcbprdtm" id="01" placeholder="выберите срок изготовки">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose option</option>
                    <option value="обычно">обычно</option>
                    <option value="срочно">срочно</option>
                    <option value="суперсрочно">суперсрочно</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="inputwrap">
                <? global $USER;
                    if ($USER->IsAuthorized()) {?>
                        <input type="submit" name="pcbsend" value="отправить" class="pcbbttn">
                        <?}
                        else {?> 
                        <div class="form-err-mssg">авторизируйтесь чтобы получить возможность отправить данные!</div>
                 <?}?>           
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $msg; var_dump(mysqli_error($result)); ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем. Нашел ответ:

```
$data=mysqli_query($conn, $query) or print(mysqli_error);
```

Прикол в том что не писал $conn и поэтому не отправляло